# css positioning/color

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would like to have an all gray background, with a smaller blue background inside it.

Something like

```
<body>
<div id= "background_1">
    <div id= "background_2">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and then in the css

```
#background_1
{
background-color : gray;
z-index : 1;
}
#background_2
{
background-color : blue;
z-index : 2; 
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? I know it is a bit vague, but I basically want an all gray background, with a smaller blue rectangle in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok with your code... but no need of z-index for that.

Perhaps, put some content into your divs, or fix their sizes

**Edit regarding your other questions**

```
// HTML
<body>
    <div id= "background">
    Test content
    </div>
</body>

// CCS
html,body
{
  margin:0 20px 0 20px;
  background-color : gray;
  height: 100%;
}
#background
{
  width:100%;
  height: auto !important; 
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  background-color : blue;
}​
```

You can see the result here : http://jsfiddle.net/Nz5WK/1/

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` only works on `position: relative`,`fixed`, or `absolute`.

Also, if it's old for looks, consider using [`border`](http://dabblet.com/gist/1857036):

```
div { width:100px; height:100px; background:lightblue; border:50px solid gray;}
```

Comment: What about if I wanted gray on the left and right side, but not the top and bottom? I want the blue to extend all the way to the top and bottom.

Comment: I also need it to extend the length of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate one of the divisions by applying the initial grey background to the body:

```
body { background: gray }
body > div.blue { background: blue }
```

```
<body>
<div class="blue">
Some text.
</div>
</body>
```

Note that in this case, the grey part will be 8px wide, as defined by the body's default margin.

---

Or, if you want the blue part to take up the entire screen with a grey "border" around it, you don't even need the division:

```
body { background: blue; border: 10px solid gray }
```

```
<body>
Some text.
</body>
```